# Including markdown converter dependency in python AWS Lambda function

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, egg

I am building a package to upload as an AWS Lambda function. In trying to include a dependency to Markdown 2.6.8, a python implementation of Markdown. When trying to test the function, I get the error `Unable to import module 'markdown-convert': No module named markdown`. I see from other similar questions that I may need to compile the dependency files inside Amazon Linux to make them usable with Lambda. I am not familiar with python and wonder if I should also be exploring the way that this code is packaged within an egg, and whether that influences how the dependency is imported. What would you suggest I pursue to try to resolve the error?

Here is the file structure of my package:

```
    .
    ├── markdown
    │   ├── blockparser.py
    │   ├── blockprocessors.py
    │   ├── extensions
    │   │   ├── abbr.py
    │   │   ├── admonition.py
    │   │   ├── attr_list.py
    │   │   ├── codehilite.py
    │   │   ├── def_list.py
    │   │   ├── extra.py
    │   │   ├── fenced_code.py
    │   │   ├── footnotes.py
    │   │   ├── headerid.py
    │   │   ├── __init__.py
    │   │   ├── meta.py
    │   │   ├── nl2br.py
    │   │   ├── __pycache__
    │   │   │   ├── abbr.cpython-34.pyc
    │   │   │   ├── admonition.cpython-34.pyc
    │   │   │   ├── attr_list.cpython-34.pyc
    │   │   │   ├── codehilite.cpython-34.pyc
    │   │   │   ├── def_list.cpython-34.pyc
    │   │   │   ├── extra.cpython-34.pyc
    │   │   │   ├── fenced_code.cpython-34.pyc
    │   │   │   ├── footnotes.cpython-34.pyc
    │   │   │   ├── headerid.cpython-34.pyc
    │   │   │   ├── __init__.cpython-34.pyc
    │   │   │   ├── meta.cpython-34.pyc
    │   │   │   ├── nl2br.cpython-34.pyc
    │   │   │   ├── sane_lists.cpython-34.pyc
    │   │   │   ├── smart_strong.cpython-34.pyc
    │   │   │   ├── smarty.cpython-34.pyc
    │   │   │   ├── tables.cpython-34.pyc
    │   │   │   ├── toc.cpython-34.pyc
    │   │   │   └── wikilinks.cpython-34.pyc
    │   │   ├── sane_lists.py
    │   │   ├── smart_strong.py
    │   │   ├── smarty.py
    │   │   ├── tables.py
    │   │   ├── toc.py
    │   │   └── wikilinks.py
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── inlinepatterns.py
    │   ├── __main__.py
    │   ├── odict.py
    │   ├── postprocessors.py
    │   ├── preprocessors.py
    │   ├── __pycache__
    │   │   ├── blockparser.cpython-34.pyc
    │   │   ├── blockprocessors.cpython-34.pyc
    │   │   ├── __init__.cpython-34.pyc
    │   │   ├── inlinepatterns.cpython-34.pyc
    │   │   ├── __main__.cpython-34.pyc
    │   │   ├── odict.cpython-34.pyc
    │   │   ├── postprocessors.cpython-34.pyc
    │   │   ├── preprocessors.cpython-34.pyc
    │   │   ├── serializers.cpython-34.pyc
    │   │   ├── treeprocessors.cpython-34.pyc
    │   │   ├── util.cpython-34.pyc
    │   │   └── __version__.cpython-34.pyc
    │   ├── serializers.py
    │   ├── treeprocessors.py
    │   ├── util.py
    │   └── __version__.py
    ├── Markdown-2.6.8.egg-info
    │   ├── dependency_links.txt
    │   ├── installed-files.txt
    │   ├── PKG-INFO
    │   ├── SOURCES.txt
    │   └── top_level.txt
    └── markdown-convert.py
```

The contents of markdown-convert.py:

```
import markdown

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    parsedHTML = {}
    parsedHTML[u'text'] = markdown.markdown(event[u'text'])
    return parsedHTML
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best advice here is to use `virtualenv` on your local development machine and install packages with `pip`.

Then when you are ready, make the lambda package by recursively copying the entire content of `<your-virtual-env>/lib/python2.7/site-packages/*`. Make sure the content is placed in the root of your zip package. This is very important!

Please, find more details here:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html